# What is the statement to create a primary key in SQL like "3585c5d240dd4132bab35ab969137f3f"

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I'm working with SQL Server Management Studio. I want to create a primary key like "3585c5d240dd4132bab35ab969137f3f" with a statement from SQL but I don't know the statement to create a primary key.
Can someone tell me what the statement is, to create a primary key like this?

Comment: Have you tried google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This value seems to be a [Universally Unique IDentifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), or UUID for short.

In MS SQL Server, you can use the [`newid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function to generate such an identifier. E.g.:

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to add a column that will store that GUID.

```
alter table your_table
add field_name uniqueidentifier not null
```

Then you need to create your primary key constraint on that field.

```
alter table your_table
add constraint PK_[your_table] PRIMARY KEY(field_name)
```

Lastly, when inserting data into your table, the field_name is generated using newid() like so:

```
insert into your_table(field_name)
values(newid())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons ADD CONSTRAINT pk_PersonID PRIMARY KEY (P_Id, LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to use a GUID. In SQL Server, the function `NEWID` (see the doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)). If you don't like dashes, use REPLACE as well:

```
 SELECT REPLACE(NEWID(), "-", "");
```

But beware of guids as primary key: [The Cost of GUIDs as Primary Keys](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly/25862). It is a bit old, but still interesting.

To make it a primary key, you can:

- declare a primary key of type varchar() in your create statement
- since functions are not allowed as default values, use *a trigger before insert* that uses the function stated above to generate your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone that says that you need to use the [NEWID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) function to generate what you want. My recommendation is that if that column will also be your clustered index, you should probably use [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx), to avoid the horrible fragmentation and page splits a random GUID column may cause.